# gcloud: Match cluster and compute zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Sometimes, I run into the following issue:

```
➢  gcloud config list
[compute]
zone = us-central1-b
[container]
cluster = my-awesome-cluster
[core]
account = pkaramol@stackoverflow.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = some-nice-project


Your active configuration is: [default]
(.venv)
~/Workspace/sail-cli  4_bug_multiple_clusters ✗                                                                                                     5h28m ⚑
➢  k get nodes
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-nodepool1-443c46af-mhmw   Ready    <none>   7h27m   v1.12.7-gke.25
gke-nodepool1-da892b44-8440   Ready    <none>   7h27m   v1.12.7-gke.25
```

Then for example I want to describe one instance (for some reason):

```
➢  gcloud compute instances describe gke-nodepool1-443c46af-mhmw
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/some-nice-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/gke-nodepool1-443c46af-mhmw' was not found
```

I guess this happens because by default, the above command performs an inquiry within the zone set here:

```
[compute]
zone = us-central1-b
```

Is there a way to set the above zone to match the gke cluster's zone?

Answer (score 2):

```
gcloud config set compute/zone <zone>
```

You can also unset the default:

```
gcloud config unset compute/zone
```

Or pass a --zone parameter to the instance command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe --zone <zone> gke-nodepool1-443c46af-mhmw
```

Comment: Personally, I think using `gcloud config` for default values (for projects, regions, zone etc.) is problematic and it's better to unset these and *always* specify the flags per your example: `--project=${PROJECT}`, `--zone=${ZONE}` etc. It's more tedious but it's a more realistic practice for the 95% (!?) of the time when you're not using a single project|zone.

Comment: Agreed!  But its nice to know that both options exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your default zone with this command

```
gcloud config set compute/zone <zone>
```

But if you have 2 clusters, each is different zones, nothing is magic. You will have to change manually your zone before requesting the resource.